# Is there a standard .NET exception to throw when a class doesn't implement a required attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, attributes

Suppose I want to throw a new exception when invoking a generic method with a type that doesn't have a required attribute. Is there a .NET exception that's appropriate for this situation, or, more likely, one that would be a suitable ancestor for a custom exception?

For example:

```
public static class ClassA
{

    public static T DoSomething<T>(string p)
    {
        Type returnType = typeof(T);
        object[] typeAttributes = returnType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SerializableAttribute), true);
        if ((typeAttributes == null) || (typeAttributes.Length == 0))
        {
             // Is there an exception type in the framework that I should use/inherit from here?
             throw new Exception("This class doesn't support blah blah blah"); 
             // Maybe ArgumentException? That doesn't seem to fit right.
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just take 30 seconds and make your own?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the way I see it, you can go one of 3 ways...

**1)** [`NotSupportedException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception.aspx)
**2)** [`NotImplementedException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.NotImplementedException.aspx)
**3)** [You can make your own Exception type](http://blog.gurock.com/articles/creating-custom-exceptions-in-dotnet/)

Answer (score 3):

I know I've seen some of the built-in code templates throw a NotImplemented exception as a placeholder, so that might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

[NotSupportedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception.aspx) is a good choice I believe. Also [TargetException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetexception.aspx) and [TargetInvocationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception.aspx) are specific for Reflection.

Answer (score 0):

NotSupportedException as NotImplemented is technically for stubs which is not what is happening here.  The type isn't supported.

That being said I don't know why MS has failed to provide canonical list with their internal definitions.  It boggles the mind.